# Continuous and Differentiable Function has a Local Maximum

Tags: maxima-minima

If $f$ is a differentiable function such that $f(a)=f(b)=0$, and there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that $f(c)>0$, prove that $f$ has a positive local maximum.

Comment: ¨Please consider the advice on [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a $\delta>0$ small enough such that $c\in(a+\delta,b-\delta)$. Since $f$ is continuous on $S=[a+\delta,b-\delta]$, $f$ attains its maximum on $S$, so $f(x_{0})=\max_{x\in[a+\delta,b-\delta]}f(x)$ for some $x_{0}\in[a+\delta,b-\delta]$, and we have $f(x_{0})\geq f(c)>0$.